# Solution of matrix differential equation $\ddot{X} = AX$ where $A$ is a Pauli matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, systems-of-equations, physics, matrix-exponential

This problem is related to a pendulum problem. Let $X := \left(\begin{matrix} x(t)\\y(t)\end{matrix}\right)$ and, $T,m,L>0$ real numbers, define also the matrix

$$A := \left(\begin{matrix} 0&-T/mL\\-T/mL &0\end{matrix}\right) = \frac{-T}{mL}\sigma_1 = -\omega_0\sigma_1$$

Where we defined $\omega_0: T/mL$. We have that  $\sigma_1:= \left(\begin{matrix} 0&1\\1 &0\end{matrix}\right)$ is one of the Pauli matrices. So we get that $\sigma_1^2 = I$ the identity matrix $2\times 2$.

> **My problem is:** solve the above differential equation, for $X(0) := X_0$, 
>   $$\ddot{X} = AX$$

---

What I tried was to use that, as $A$ is a constant matrix we get that $X(t) = X_0e^{At}$. Then the problem is to find $e^{At}$.

$$e^{At} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(At)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-\omega_0t)^n\sigma_1^n}{n!} = I\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega_0t)^{2n}}{(2n)!}-\sigma_1\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\omega_0t)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \implies$$

$$e^{At} = I\cosh(\omega_0t)-\sigma_1\sinh(\omega_0t) = \left(\begin{matrix} \cosh(\omega_0t)&-\sinh(\omega_0t)\\-\sinh(\omega_0t) &\cosh(\omega_0t)\end{matrix}\right)$$

But this is clearly wrong. Set $X_0 =\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\0\end{matrix} \right)$ and we get for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

$$x(t) = \cosh(\omega_0t)$$

$$y(t) = -\sinh(\omega_0t)$$

But $\ddot{x}(t) = \omega_0^2\cosh(\omega_0 t)\neq -\omega_0y(t)$

Comment: Note, that you cannot use the matrix exponential for a second order system. The matrix exponential is only applicable for **first order linear time-invariant** systems. Your ODE is time-invariant and linear but is not of first order.

Comment: Were it a system $\ddot{X} = - A^2 X$ you could have found the solution in the form $X(t) = C_1 \cos{At} + C_2 \sin{At}$ :)

Comment: @MrYouMath That's my answer, please answer that so that a can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that you cannot use the matrix exponential for a second order system. The matrix exponential is only applicable for **first order linear time-invariant systems (first order LTI)**. Your ODE is time-invariant and linear but is not of first order.

If you had a **fist order linear time-variant (first order LTV)** system you could apply the [Peano-Baker-series](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.1775.pdf).

Another way to solve your problem would be to put it into the first-order form by introducing intermediate variables such that the resulting system is a linear first order system which is time-invariant and then apply the matrix exponential method.

Answer (score 2):

I'd skip using the matrix exponential approach. You can easily decouple the equations

$$\ddot{x} = - \omega_0 y$$

$$\ddot{y} = - \omega_0 x$$

by differentiating the first equation twice and plugging this into the second, arriving at

$$\ddddot{x} = \omega_0^2 x$$

Use $x(t) = e^{rt}$ and you're left solving

$$r^4 - \omega_0^2 = 0$$

for the characteristic roots.

Comment: But you see what was the problem on my approach? Also, thank you for your answer (+1)

Comment: You did not decouple the differential equation you just solved it by transforming the system into a scalar differential equation.